# Qt5 - How to make qurl detect wether the given url is local or not and add "http://" if not?

Tags: qt, qt5, qurl

`QUrl` class can be used to open both local or online file. I used `QLineEdit` to take URL as `QString` and give it to `QUrl`. The program can access both local and online file. My point question is: is there any official way to automatically detect if the given url is local or online and add `http://` automatically if the url is online?

For example, if user type `www.google.com`, it should be online and should be added `http://` before it being processed. If user type `/home/username/somepath` it should be offline.

Of course a little `if` and `else` thing with string pattern check can be used for this purpose. My question is, if there's officially supported way to do something like this from Qt5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [QUrl:fromUserInput(...)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromUserInput) for that purpose.

```
QString first("qt-project.org");
QString second("ftp.qt-project.org");
QString third("hostname");
QString fourth("/home/user/test.html");

qDebug() << QUrl::fromUserInput(first);   // QUrl( "http://qt-project.org" )       
qDebug() << QUrl::fromUserInput(second);  // QUrl( "ftp://ftp.qt-project.org" )    
qDebug() << QUrl::fromUserInput(third);   // QUrl( "http://hostname" )             
qDebug() << QUrl::fromUserInput(fourth);  // QUrl( "file:///home/user/test.html" )
```

Comment: this answer has small shortage. It would be better to mention that local url can be queried by `isLocalFile()` like this: `if (QUrl::fromUserInput(file).isLocalFile()) { /*...do something...*/}`